# Rails 4 authorization using roles

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm developing some Rails application, and I want to make a super user which can add moderators. Moderator is a user which have some business - restaurant, shop, etc, therefore each moderator's type (restaurant-owner, shop-owner, etc) has different layout, different actions. Ability to add a new moderator is only available for the super user. Please, suggest me any gem for my task, thanks for advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'll prefer to use **Cancan gem** which is one of the good authorization gem in raiils.
[Cancan rails](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Role-Based-Authorization)

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend to use the gem `declarative_authorization`

Declarative authorization provides an advanced and powerful solution for role based authorization.

Ref:

- https://rubygems.org/gems/declarative_authorization
- https://github.com/stffn/declarative_authorization
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/188-declarative-authorization

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

There are so many ***gems/plugins*** available for ***Role-based authorization***.Have a look at the most popular among them.

**[Cancan](https://rubygems.org/gems/cancan)([Git](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan))**

**[Rolify](https://rubygems.org/gems/rolify)([Git](https://github.com/EppO/rolify))**

**[Canard](https://rubygems.org/gems/canard)([Git](https://github.com/james2m/canard))**

**[Acl9](https://rubygems.org/gems/acl9)([Git](https://github.com/be9/acl9))**

**[Pundit](https://rubygems.org/gems/pundit)([Git](https://github.com/elabs/pundit))**

And also see this **[link](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_authorization)** for more.

Hope it helps!